# How to make webpack not use the window object when bundling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, module

I'm making a React component library to abstract out some components I use in multiple projects. Some projects are made with CRA, some with Gatsby, some might be something else, etc. I used the Neutrino.js framework/toolchain as it was linked on the React docs site, but the issue I ran into is that by default the output files of the build all use the `window` object, which causes `gatsby build` to break as `window` doesn't exist in Node/SSR. Is there a way to make Neutrino/webpack output a bundle that doesn't use window? While searching for a solution and comparing to other libraries it seems that ESM is the best but I'm not sure how to get webpack to use it, I think it's currently not supported. Is there another tool I should be using for this?

Comment: Where would I put the `
import window from 'window';` statement? If I put it in my component that gets built in the library, I get a cannot resolve window, and the same happens when I put it inside the app that imports my component. (and if I ignore it I get react error 321)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add [globalObject](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject) configuration to your webpack configuration:

```
output: {
    globalObject: "this",
  },
```

The default is `window`

For example:

To make UMD build available on both browsers and Node.js, set output.globalObject option to 'this'.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    library: 'myLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'myLib.js',
    globalObject: 'this'
  }
};
```

-From docs

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: I'm pulling my hair out right now becuase no matter WHAT I set "globalObject" to it gets overridden somehwere an always compiles to "self"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67872307/why-would-webpack-output-with-global-self-instead-of-this-when-output-global