# Why would webpack output with global `self` instead of `this` when output.globalObject: "this" is specified?

Tags: node.js, webpack, compilation, global-object

I am using webpack-cli 4.7.0. I have a library that I would like to compile for two different environments, one for web and one for node. According to [this documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) this is easily achieved my exporting two separate, valid webpack configurations from webpack.config.js.

So I have created two valid webpack configs, one for server and one for client. Webpack outputs two separate files as specified, but insists on using "self" instead of "this" even though I have `output.globalObject: "this"` specified in the configuration. If I am understanding the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject), such should not be the case.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require( "path" );
// const webpack = require( "webpack" );


const serverConfig  = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/Check4.js",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, "dist" ),
        filename: "Check4.node.js",
        globalObject: "this",
        library : {
            type: "commonjs2",
            export: "default"

        }

    }
};

const clientConfig  = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/Check4.web.js",
    target: "web",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, "dist" ),
        filename: "Check4.js",
        globalObject: "this",
        library : {
            name: "Check4",
            type: "window",
        }
    }
};

module.exports = [serverConfig, clientConfig];
```

for reference, here are the first several bytes output by webpack to show that it is using global "self" instead of "this"

```
(()=>{var e={172:e=>{self,e.exports=(()=>{"use strict";var e={502:...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in my dependencies. I had written a class which this class depended upon. The parent class was not compiled, so webpack was trying to compile both at the same time.

After many hours I stumpbled upon this which led me to solving the issue.
https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/issues/79

> Hey, update; After looking around a tad, it looks like for me, this
> error is coming from isomorphic-fetch dependency
> ([https://github.com/matthew-andrews/iso…](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/iso%E2%80%A6)). Seems similar to document
> is not defined kind of issues people get, since this pre rendering
> doesn't happen in a browser context. I don't have any more time to
> look at it today for why that's the case or for solutions, but that's
> my hunch. Check your polyfills and dependencies.